# WPF C# MVC/MVP pattern and user control code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller, mvp, code-behind

I am developing a large-ish application in WPF/WCF/NHibernate/etc. and have implemented the MVP pattern (although this question is still relevant to MVC) as the core architecture.

It feels quite natural to extend and add functionality as well as to come back and make changes on certain bits and pieces, as far as the core architecture is concerned (controllers, views, etc).

But at times the code-behind-ness of custom user controls that I create feels as if it "breaks" the MVC/MVP paradigm implemented, in that code concerns leak in the design and design concerns leak in the code. Let me clarify again, this is only for user controls. It is my personal opinion that this code-behind model (for both ASP.NET and WPF) is a 'Bad Thing', but no matter what my opinion, I'm stuck with it.

What are your recommendations for best practices in such a scenario? How do you handle such concerns? Do you for instance work around the code-behind-ness of custom controls and if so how??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using WPF, you should really look into the [MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern. It is a form of the [Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) (PM) pattern discussed by [Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/). WPF is very binding-oriented, and provides a very powerful and rich data binding framework for XAML. Using MVVM, you can completely and entirely decouple your ViewModels from your Views, allowing truly POCO UI development that offers the ultimate in separation of concerns and unit testability.

With MVVM, you will be able to modularize and decouple all of your views, including Windows, UserControls, etc., from the code that drives them. You should have no logic in Code Behind other than what is automatically generated for you. Some things are a little tricky at first, but the following links should get you started. The key things to learn are the MVVM pattern itself, Data Binding, Routed Events and Commands, and Attached Behaviors:

- [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)
- [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx)
- [Attached Behaviors](http://www.bjoernrochel.de/2009/08/19/the-attached-behavior-pattern/)

  - [Attached Commands (VERY USEFUL!)](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/)
- [Routed Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)
- [Routed Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)

WPF + MVVM has a bit of a learning curve up front, but once you get over the initial hurdle, you will never, ever want to look back. The composability, lose coupling, data binding, and raw power of WPF and MVVM are astonishing. You'll have more freedom with your UI than you ever had before, and you will rarely, if ever, have to actually bother with code behind.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to like code-behinds (yet another personal opinion), but they work only as long as they do nothing but facilitate interactions between control events and the rest of the application. I'll admit that I've seen a lot of counter-examples, though. I even wrote a few of them....

Really, all the code-behind should do is "oh, someone clicked this button; there's probably something that wants to know about that." PRISM (from MS patterns and practices) provides a lot of architectural infrastructure for WPF and Silverlight; that includes a publish/subscribe interface that allows the controls and the code-behinds to simply publish an event while not even being aware of possible subscribers, or what the subscribers might do with the event. PRISM also adds commands for Silverlight.

A common variant of MVC for WPF and Silverlight is MVVM (Model, View, ViewModel). The ViewModel makes data available to the user controls in some form that is most useful (such as ObservableCollections, to facilitate two-way binding).

Answer (score 0):

Custom Controls are there to display stuff. In that regard they are no different than a button or a drop down combo box. The trick is that don't let them handle stuff directly. They need to send stuff through the View Interface and the Presenter need to likewise interact with them through the view interface.

Think of it this way. If you ignored MVP the custom control would interact with the model in specific ways. what you doing with MVP is taking those way and defining them with the View Interface. Yes you are adding an extra call layer but the advantage is that you thoroughly document how it interacting with the rest of the system. Plus you get the advantage of being able to rip it out and replace with something entirely different. Because all the new thing needs to do is the implement it's portion of the view interface.

If you have a specific example I can illustrate better.